# Upgrading Fedora 25 to 32 "rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by ..." errors

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, dnf, dist-upgrade

After running `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=32 --allowerasing` I get the following gigantic list of errors:

```
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by python3-audit-3.0-0.19.20191104git1c2f876.fc32.x86_64
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by kexi-3.1.0-7.fc32.x86_64
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by kexi-libs-3.1.0-7.fc32.x86_64
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by alternatives-1.11-6.fc32.x86_64
...
```

After reading https://serverfault.com/questions/280099/how-do-i-install-an-rpm-that-complains-about-rpmlibfiledigests-4-6-0-1 I gather this is because some RPM version between the ones for Fedora-25 and Fedora-32 introduced a "PayloadIsZstd" feature.

How can I fix this?

I tried backing up rpm and rpm-libs files and force-installing the Fedora 32 rpm (on the odd chance existing binaries would be compatible?):

```
# Probably a really stupid idea. Don't do this, it's super hard to undo.
$ sudo rpm -ivhU ~/Downloads/rpm-libs-4.15.1-3.fc32.1.x86_64.rpm ~/Downloads/rpm-4.15.1-3.fc32.1.x86_64.rpm --replacepkgs --nodeps --force --nomd5
...
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: Bad magic
```

Now I'm thinking I should try intermediate versions, e.g. hopefully the Fedora 30 rpm has PayloadIsZstd.

Is there a better way?

---

UPDATE

I ended up upgrading to Fedora 30 first and then on to 32 to solve the rpm feature dependency, which solved the above. There were still some [dependency issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603565/error-transaction-check-vs-depsolve-php-dependencies). The first install failed (rebooted back into FC25), I'm guessing because I still had packages queued up from `--releasever=32` and didn't remove those first before choosing `--releasever=30`. Simply repeating `dnf system-upgrade` + `dnf system-upgrade reboot` worked the second time.

Comment: Fedora upgrades of versions greater than N+2 are [not officially supported][1]

I recently had to do upgrade a machine that was running an even older Fedora version, and upgrading version by version, everything worked fine


  [1]: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-system-upgrade/#sect-how-many-releases-can-i-upgrade-across-at-once

Answer (score 3):

According to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Switch_RPMs_to_zstd_compression Zstd compression was introduced in Fedora 31, so maybe you could first try installing rpm-libs from Fedora 31 prior to upgrading. This won't necessarily work because rpm-libs might depend on other not yet installed libraries e.g. glibc. In short I don't see a simple way out for you. Probably reinstalling from scratch is now a better idea.

Comment: From scratch would probably have been simpler. I ended up going through fedora 30 (i.e. system-upgrade from 25 -> 30 -> 32), which worked around `PayloadIsZstd`.

Comment: Considering your upgrade path you ran Fedora 25 which had stopped receiving any updates ages ago for quite some time. That's generally not a good idea.